# Failure to change values by reference of variables "firstNum" and "secondNum" in function "calcValues"

Tags: c++

This program accepts feet and inches and converts them into meters and centimeters.

My main concern is outputting the right values, all other help with the other two problems would be greatly appreciated!

There are several things I am having problems with, I will list them in order of importance:

I am outputting the same values that is being inputted into the computer ( no mathematical operations I have constructed are taking place I believe. Example: I input 12 feet 6 inches and it returns 12 meters 6 centimeters

My do-while loop is not presenting the option to input y/n to repeat the program (I believe I must have my do-while loop in the wrong place)

I don’t believe that the output would be presented correctly even if the mathematical operations were to be working. For example: If I input 12 feet 9 inches this will equate to 3.65 meters and 22.86 centimeters but the problem here is that the .65 in the 3.65 meters can be added to centimeters so that it fully converts into a whole number in meters with the remainder added into centimeters (b/c 1 meter = 100 centimeters) but unfortunately I can not use the modulos operator (%) because this only works with integer operators and I don’t think a "static cast" would work here if I wanted to convert meters of data type double to data type int so that the modulos operator will work

renaming variables in calValues function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void getNumbers(double& input1, double& input2);
void calcValues(double& variable1, double& variable2);
void showResults(double& result1, double& result2);

int main()
{
  double firstNum, secondNum;
  char ans;
  cout << "This program accepts feet and inches " << endl;
  cout << "to convert them into meters and centimeters." << endl;
  do
  {
    getNumbers(firstNum, secondNum);
    calcValues(firstNum, secondNum);
    showResults(firstNum, secondNum);
  } while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
  cout << "Thank you for using the program." << endl;
  return 0;
}

void getNumbers(double& input1, double& input2)
{
  cout << "Enter in number of feet:" << endl;
  cin >> input1;
  cout << "Enter in number of inches:" << endl;
  cin >> input2;
}

void calcValues(double& variable1, double& variable2)
{
  const double METER = 0.3048, CENTI = 100, INCH = 12;
  double finalMeter, finalCenti, tempFeet, tempMeter;

  finalMeter = (variable1 * METER);

  tempFeet = (variable2 / INCH);
  tempMeter = (tempFeet * METER);
  finalCenti = (tempMeter * CENTI);
}

void showResults(double& result1, double& result2)
{
  cout.setf(ios::fixed);
  cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
  cout.precision(2);
  cout << "The feet and inches you entered equates to " << endl;
  cout << result1 << " meters and " << result2 << " centimeters." << endl;
  cout << "Would you like to enter in " << endl;
  cout << "new values for feet and inches? (y/n)" << endl;
}
```

Comment: In `calcValues` you only modify local variables, not arguments.

Comment: And don't pass by value if you're not modifying the arguments (for example for the `showResults` function).

Answer (score 0):

In `calcValues` you must actually assign to `variable1` and `variable2` if you want to change what they refer to, e.g.

```
void calcValues(double& variable1, double& variable2)
{
  const double METER = 0.3048, CENTI = 100, INCH = 12;
  double finalMeter, finalCenti, tempFeet, tempMeter;

  finalMeter = variable1 * METER;

  tempFeet = variable2 / INCH;
  tempMeter = tempFeet * METER;
  finalCenti = tempMeter * CENTI;
  variable1 = finalMeter;
  variable2 = finalCenti;
}
```

You really don't need all those brackets either.

PS I suspect that the calculation is wrong, but I'll leave you to sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
char ans;
void calcValues(double& variable1, double& variable2)
```

You need to initialize/input ans and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I believe I am interacting with the "variables" now (terminology may be wrong) I am able to see my output change as opposed to showing the same numbers I inputted in the beginning but I still am unsure that, in the showResults function where I initialize my finalMeter and finalCenti to the function calcValues, the parameters are right because I want to interact with only one part of the function calcValues (just meters for example) and not both parts and I assume if I include calcValues(input1, input2) that this will cause both numbers to be included in the output and the compiler i am using (repl) will not allow me to just pass only one parameter for example calcVaules(input1) I assume this will allow me to display only the 1st number.

I am playing around with this code alot and drawing from other examples to see how they formatted their code but it has to be that I do not understand the full logic of where the data is being moved (variable to variable) I know the pass by reference applies to the location of the variable itself as opposed to passing a copy of it in a pass by value (I may have butchered the definition/my understand of these concepts)

Once again all the help is very much appreciated and I understand what yall are saying but it is hard to translate that into a workable code snippet that would allow this program to run,

thanks again :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getNumbers(double& input1, double& input2);
double calcValues(double& variable1, double& variable2);
void showResults(double& output1, double& output2);

int main()
{
  double firstNum, secondNum;
  char ans;

  cout << "This program accepts feet and inches " << endl;
  cout << "to convert them into meters and centimeters." << endl;

  do
  {
    getNumbers(firstNum, secondNum); 
    calcValues(firstNum, secondNum);
    showResults(firstNum, secondNum);
  }while (ans == 'y' || ans =='Y');

  cout << "Thank you for using the program." << endl;
  return 0;
}
void getNumbers(double& input1, double& input2)
{
  cout << "Enter in number of feet:" << endl;
  cin >> input1;
  cout << "Enter in number of inches:" << endl;
  cin >> input2;
}
double calcValues(double& meters, double& centimeters)
{
  const double METER = 0.3048, CENTI = 2.54, INCH = 12;


  meters = (meters * METER);

  centimeters = (centimeters * CENTI);

}
void showResults(double& input1, double& input2)
{
  double finalMeter, finalCenti;

  finalMeter = calcValues(input1, input2);
  finalCenti = calcValues(input1, input2);

  cout.setf(ios::fixed);
  cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
  cout.precision(2);
  cout << "The feet and inches you entered equates to " << endl;
  cout << finalMeter << " meters and " <<
  finalCenti << " centimeters." << endl;
  cout << "Would you like to enter in " << endl;
  cout << "new values for feet and inches? (y/n)" << endl;
}
```